# Method return type contains subclass definition

Tags: java, generics, return-type, covariant

I come up with a code that uses a syntax like this:

```
public <A extends B> double[][] foo(C arg) {
.... }
```

I get a couple of questions by viewing it.

a) The return type of `foo(C arg)` is `<A extends B> double[][]`? What does this mean? I would understood a return type like `double[][]` for example, but I cannot determine what does the previous modifier (maybe?) `<A extends B>` does?

b) Why there is a subclass declaration inside a return type? Since A is a subclass of B where do we override or add any methods/members etc? To me it seems that it's a subclass containing just the same methods/members of the base class A. Isn't so? So is there any difference in writing `public <A> double[][] foo(C arg)`?

c) Finally I suppose that <> have to do with Java generics but even then I have seen declaration like `D<T>` which T is used to parametrize the raw type `D`. Here I tried to remove the <> (since I don't understand what they stand for) but compiler complains.

Comment: You my friend need to read about 1)Generics -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ and 2)How to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

1. The return type is `double[][]`. The `<A extends B>` part is the parametrization of the [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)
2. The [restriction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) `extends B` implies that only generic types `A` extending or actually implementing `B` are allowed in this method.
3. Cannot answer your third question as it would require the code in the method's body and more context.