# Concrete subclasses of abstract class as parameters in raw class without abstract methods implementation

Tags: java, parameters, abstract-class

I am working with boofCV and I found at some point a class that is deinfed as:

```
public class WrapDetectDescribeSurf
        <T extends ImageSingleBand, II extends ImageSingleBand>
    implements DetectDescribePoint<T,SurfFeature>
{...}
```

I found that `ImageSingleBand` is an abstract class with at least 3 abstract methods:

```
protected abstract Object _getData();
public abstract ImageTypeInfo<T> getTypeInfo();
protected abstract void _setData(Object data);
```

As far as I know to create a concrete subclass of an abstract one you should implement the abstract method of the base class. I could not find any implementation of these methods in the above code. And I cannot understand where this implementation could have been put. I mean both `T` and `II` are defined inside parameterization of the raw class `WrapDetectDescribeSurf`.

So what happens here? You don't need implementation of the abstract methods? I have asked a somehow similar question here: [Method return type contains subclass definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425328/method-return-type-contains-subclass-definition) but I did not fully solve my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementations of ImageSingleBand must implement the abstract methods.

The Generics declaration T and II are just declarations, which tell the compiler, that T and II are classes which *extend* ImageSingleBand. In other words: T and II will be subclasses of ImageSingleBand.

So a instantiation of 'WrapDetectDescribeSurf' could look something like this:

```
new WrapDetectDescribeSurf<ImageInteger, ImageFloat>();
```

ImageInteger and ImageFloat are concrete subclasses of ImageSingleBand.

To be more specific:

Subclasses of ImageSingleBand (http://boofcv.org/javadoc/boofcv/struct/image/ImageSingleBand.html) can be

- ImageFloat (http://boofcv.org/javadoc/boofcv/struct/image/ImageFloat.html)
- ImageInteger (../struct/image/ImageInteger.html)
- ImageSInt64 (../struct/image/ImageSInt64.html)

These classes implement the abstract methods.

Comment: Yes but where are the implementations? You did not specify an answer on this question